# Equality of Expected value for the product of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I have the following question:   Assume that $X$ and $X_{1}$ are two random variables with identical distribution (in particular $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X_{1}]$). Equally we have that $Y$ and $Y_{1}$ are two random variables with identical distribution (again, we have $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[Y_{1}]$).

Is it true then that $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[X_{1}Y_{1}]$?  I suspect it is, but I am stuck trying to prove this.  Any clues if this is true or not?  If so, how can this be proven?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be answered unless we know the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ and of $(X_1, Y_1)$. If the two pairs are independent, then the left-hand and right-hand sides become $E[X] E[Y]$ and $E[X_1]E[Y_1]$ respectively which are equal.

Otherwise they may not be equal. Consider a situation where $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli$(1/2)$, and where $X_1=Y_1$ is Bernoulli($1/2$). Then $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y] = 1/4$, but $E[X_1Y_1] = E[X_1]=1/2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!